# Rails update page w/o prototype?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I'm trying (still) to get ajaxful-rating to work with my rails installation.  I did not install my app with prototype because I like jQuery.

The tutorial (and everyone else) has said to use this to render the update

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html id, ratings_for(@entry, :wrap => false, :dimension => params[:dimension])
  page.visual_effect :highlight, id
end
```

However, I get a 'undefined local variable or method 'id''...I can get the gem working *without ajax* by doing a standard:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @entry }
  format.js { render :layout => false}
end
```

I guess I could always just do a jQuery.ajax call, but I'd like to implement this as tightly into my rails app as possible--I want to learn to do it the right way. :)

Please please please help.  I've definitely resorted to begging for help.

Comment: In the line `page.replace_html id, ...`, where and how is that id variable being set? You say you are getting an error that `id` is undefined, so that may be the extent of your troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it since I prefer to decouple everything (that is, the page should work without being depending on javascript at all), but have a look at the jquery rails plugin http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails

It might do what you want since it is supposed to be a complete replacement for prototype.

However, the error sounds like you are missing some initialization. Try with using `params[:id]` instead.

Comment: The page does work without javascript--I just don't know how to get this ajax-ified.

Comment: Ok, but then try the jquery-rails gem and see if that solves the problem. Or upgrade to rails 3.1 which includes it already out of the box (only do this if you're just starting though since it is still in pre and not released yet so I don't even know why I mention it :))

Comment: I already have jquery-rails included in my gemfile...and I run `bundle install` a lot. :/ Weird? Is there something I need to do to tell rails that this should be rendered as js and not html?

Comment: hmm, ok. Then I have no idea. No, since you are receiving the data and not a redirect shows that it do render it according to the type (´render.js` is being called). But you're saying you get the javascript back, but it is being inserted as text into the browser? How do you do the call? You might need to add `{dataType:'script'}` to the `jQuery.ajax` call

Comment: Just as a side note: jRails was the best solution.  It renders rjs as jQuery instead of prototype.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is supposed to be the dom id of the ratings element that you are trying to replace with new ratings. So look what the `id` is and replace `id` in your code with that string.

You could also write the JS code manually without relying on RJS.

Something like this

```
$("#YOUR_ID_HERE").html("<%= escape_javascript ratings_for(@entry, :wrap => false, :dimension => params[:dimension]) %>");
$("#YOUR_ID_HERE").effect("highlight");
```

Put this code in your view, name it `your_action.js.erb` (replace the your_action with your action name of course). Then your standard respond_to block should work

Comment: Right! I did that and now I get a bunch of js spit back at me.  What do I do then?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code. Did you install jquery-rails like Jimmy suggested?

Comment: Well "render :update" generates javascript for you. And I'm pretty sure it uses Prototype. So skip that and generate javascript yourself and use jQuery. If you compare my code with the "render :update" one, you will notice that they are doing the same thing. RJS just abstracts it.

Comment: I've been wondering about that...I'm really new to rails. I have a page named `rate.js.erb`...how do I get that to run?  I think my app is still trying to render it as html--it's just sending me to a blank page.
I changed my :update to this:
`    respond_to do |format|
     format.js
    end
`

Comment: Sorry, egaze. Jimmy got it. You're very close too, though. :)